# Choosing predictor for regression

Tags: regression

If a predictor is almost the same as the criterion (different tests measuring same domain and they are both highly correlated) would that predictor be worth-including in the regression model? What if if yields the highest part correlation vs other predictors in the model?

Answer (score 1):

There can be two reasons why you may want to include a variable in a regression model

1. This is the predictor variable of interest
2. You think it influences **both** the criterion variables and the predictor variable of interest.

So the fact that some variable influences your criterion variable is on its own not enough to include it in your model. You also need to make it plausible that it coul also influence the predictor variable of interest and not the other way around, i.e. that it is a confounding variable not an intervening variable.

If your predictor is not the predictor variable of interest, than I don't think you should include it in your model. You could however start thinking about using it to get a better measurement of your criterion (think structural equation modeling).